# Loading NSArray UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a tabbed view controller and I put a table view in it but when I run the program I got this EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

The array does not get loaded and produces this error.

Here is my code:

**ContactsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic ,retain)  NSArray *items;

@end
```

**ContactsViewController.m**

```
#import "ContactsViewController.h"

@interface ContactsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ContactsViewController

@synthesize items;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", "item3", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

[image: Array]

Comment: Please explain the problem properly.

Comment: i have a table view and i want to load my array into it but when i run the program i have this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code lies (as the debugger tells you) in the following line:

```
items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", "item3", nil];
```

Take a closer look at "item3". There is no `@` sign in front of it so it is not an `NSString` object but a plain old C string. You can only put objects into an `NSArray`.

Change it to

```
items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", nil];
```

or even simpler

```
item = @[@"item1", @"item2", @"item3"];
```

Comment: thank you HAS its done perfectly.but now there is another problem.its an empty table not a single thing appears

Comment: I bet there appear 3 cells! But you don't see them since they are plain. In your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` modify the cell you create like this `cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item];`

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeees it worked thank you.. really really thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code it's not possible to say for sure what the problem is, but you should access the variable through the property in the following way.

```
self.items = ...
```

Also consider using the shorthand array notation, like this.

```
self.items = @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3"];
```

IMO: The only time you should use variables directly is in an overriden property accessory.

Also note that if you do want to use the variable directly you should change the synthesize command to the following `@synthesize items = variableName;` This puts a name, `variableName` on the underlying variable used in the property. You can then access the variable without going through the property.

Comment: its not loaded even when i use this

Comment: my array items my friend

Comment: Can you added the full code for the .h and .m file in your original question?

Comment: Did you try using self.items instead? The reason your code fails is most likely because the ivar created by synthesize will be called `_items` and not `items`. Try using `self.items` in all the places where you use `items` right now.

Comment: the same didn't change anything.could it be the storyboard ?? but don't think so